# AS3: How to use array element as URLRequest parameter?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, urlrequest

First I use URLRequest to read a txt file contain multiple lines of String

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("listOfJsonFile.txt");
```

and I had created a array

```
private var listOfJson:Array = new Array();
```

Then I split each string into array

```
var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);

listOfJson = loader.data.split(/\n/);

trace(listOfJson[0]); // return XXX.Json
```

**Question:**

How can I do:

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(listOfJson[0]);
```

> Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error.

I have try create a temp var string or cast the element to String().

I did: `var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("XXX.json");` and it work.

Comment: Can you post what the file contents looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your text file contains `\r` (carriage return) characters as well as `\n` (newlines)? That depends on your operating system. When you split on `\n` characters only, those CR characters remain part of the file name you try to load, and the file `XXX.json\r` doesn't likely exist.

So use `split("\r\n")` and see if that helps.
If that doesn't help, it may even be the other way round (I keep forgetting the actual order: `split("\n\r")`).